# C++11 vector with two GLfloats as pair fail to uniform initialize

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, initializer-list, std-pair

The error message of gcc 4.9.2 is:

```
could not convert from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<std::pair<float, float> >'
```

of this code:

```
vector<pair<GLfloat, GLfloat>> LightOneColorsPairVec {{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}};
```

The code is compiled with 'std=c++11' compiler flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all because [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) doesn't have  [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) that takes a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). Secondly because `std::pair` is a *pair*, it only have two values, not four.

Comment: You do not need a `initializer_list` constructor to use the braced form of initialization, so I'm not sure I'm seeing what the point of the first sentence is.

Answer (score 0):

As Joachim Pileborg pointed out pairs are not similar to vectors, so I converted the code to this:

```
vector<vector<vector<GLfloat>>> LightColorsVec {{{0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}}};
```

And it works for multiple light sources now.